# TTL cache for AsyncContextManager

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'd like to keep an `AsyncContextManager` that might be reused, alive for some seconds so it doesn't have to be recreated.
Things I like to fix, but don't know how:

- Make kind of `@ttl_cache(ttl=1.5, parallel=False)` attribute for `asynccontextmanager` attributed methods
- get rid of using "dunder" methods (`__aenter__`, `__aexit__`) explicitly
- ensure proper exception handling
- protect against duplicate init of same key
- optionally protect against parallel usage of same `AsyncContextManager` while in context

That's what I tried:

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import time, logging, sys

logging.basicConfig(format="{relativeCreated:5.0f} ms - {message}", style="{", level=logging.DEBUG,stream=sys.stdout)

class SomeCM:
    def __init__(self):
        logging.debug(f"{__class__.__qualname__}.init")

    async def __aenter__(self):
        logging.debug(f"{__class__.__qualname__}.enter")
        return self
    
    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        logging.debug(f"{__class__.__qualname__}.exit")

    async def work(self):
        logging.debug(f"{__class__.__qualname__}.work")

# FIXME: want
#@ttl_cache(ttl=1.5, parallel=False)
#@asynccontextmanager
#async def make_SomeCM(arg):
#    async with SomeCM(arg) as cm:
#        yield cm


get_cm_cache = {}  # used to store alive AsyncContextManagers, references, last_access, cleanup_task

@asynccontextmanager
async def get_cached_cm(make, *args, ttl=10):
    "call method `make`(`*args`) to create an AsyncContextManager and keep alive for `ttl` seconds after last usage"
    __funcname__ = "get_cached_cm"
    key = (make, args)
    if key not in get_cm_cache:
        # FIXME: ensure noone creates cm for same key until it is created
        cm_obj = make(*args)
        cm = await cm_obj.__aenter__()  # FIXME: remove dunder method

        async def cleanup():
            try:
                while True:
                    now = time.monotonic()
                    cm, refs, last_access, _ = get_cm_cache[key]
                    if refs == 0:
                        remaining = last_access + ttl - now
                        if remaining <= 0:
                            break
                        logging.debug(f"{__funcname__}({key}): keep alive for {remaining:.1f} seconds")
                    else:
                        remaining = ttl
                        logging.debug(f"{__funcname__}({key}): keep alive due to {refs} references")
                    await asyncio.sleep(remaining)
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                logging.debug(f"{__funcname__}({key}): cancel keep alive, {refs} references")
            finally:
                logging.debug(f"{__funcname__}({key}): remove from cache")
                del get_cm_cache[key]
                logging.debug(f"{__funcname__}({key}): terminate")
                await cm.__aexit__(None, None, None)  # FIXME: remove dunder method and fix exception handling
                logging.debug(f"{__funcname__}({key}): terminated")

        exit_task = asyncio.create_task(cleanup())
        get_cm_cache[key] = (cm, 0, time.monotonic(), exit_task)
        
    cm, refs, _, exit_task = get_cm_cache[key]
    refs += 1
    get_cm_cache[key] = (cm, refs, time.monotonic(), exit_task)
    logging.debug(f"{__funcname__}({key}): add reference")
    # FIXME: if not parallel ensure noone else uses cm until finally
    try:
        yield cm
    finally:
        cm, refs, _, exit_task = get_cm_cache[key]
        refs -= 1
        get_cm_cache[key] = (cm, refs, time.monotonic(), exit_task)
        logging.debug(f"{__funcname__}({key}): remove reference")


async def main():
    for i in range(4):
        try:
            async with get_cached_cm(SomeCM, ttl=1.5) as cm:
                await cm.work()
                logging.debug(f"{cm.__class__.__qualname__} use in iteration {i}")
        except MyException as exc:
            logging.debug(f"Caught {exc}")
        logging.debug(f"Do some work for {i} seconds")
        await asyncio.sleep(i)
    logging.debug("Done all iterations")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Example run with `ttl = 1.5`:

```
   44 ms - SomeCM.init
   45 ms - SomeCM.enter
   45 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): add reference
   45 ms - SomeCM.work
   45 ms - SomeCM use in iteration 0
   45 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): remove reference
   46 ms - Do some work for 0 seconds
   46 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): keep alive for 1.5 seconds
   46 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): add reference
   47 ms - SomeCM.work
   47 ms - SomeCM use in iteration 1
   47 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): remove reference
   47 ms - Do some work for 1 seconds
 1049 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): add reference
 1049 ms - SomeCM.work
 1050 ms - SomeCM use in iteration 2
 1050 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): remove reference
 1050 ms - Do some work for 2 seconds
 1544 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): keep alive for 1.0 seconds
 2569 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): remove from cache
 2569 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): terminate
 2570 ms - SomeCM.exit
 2570 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): terminated
 3067 ms - SomeCM.init
 3067 ms - SomeCM.enter
 3068 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): add reference
 3068 ms - SomeCM.work
 3068 ms - SomeCM use in iteration 3
 3068 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): remove reference
 3069 ms - Do some work for 3 seconds
 3069 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): keep alive for 1.5 seconds
 4576 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): remove from cache
 4576 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): terminate
 4576 ms - SomeCM.exit
 4577 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): terminated
 6087 ms - Done all iterations
```

Example run with `ttl = 5`:

```
   47 ms - SomeCM.init
   47 ms - SomeCM.enter
   47 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): add reference
   48 ms - SomeCM.work
   48 ms - SomeCM use in iteration 0
   48 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): remove reference
   48 ms - Do some work for 0 seconds
   49 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): keep alive for 5.0 seconds
   49 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): add reference
   49 ms - SomeCM.work
   50 ms - SomeCM use in iteration 1
   50 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): remove reference
   50 ms - Do some work for 1 seconds
 1053 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): add reference
 1054 ms - SomeCM.work
 1054 ms - SomeCM use in iteration 2
 1054 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): remove reference
 1054 ms - Do some work for 2 seconds
 3061 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): add reference
 3061 ms - SomeCM.work
 3062 ms - SomeCM use in iteration 3
 3062 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): remove reference
 3062 ms - Do some work for 3 seconds
 5058 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): keep alive for 3.0 seconds
 6081 ms - Done all iterations
 6081 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): cancel keep alive, 0 references
 6081 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): remove from cache
 6082 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): terminate
 6082 ms - SomeCM.exit
 6082 ms - get_cached_cm((<class '__main__.SomeCM'>, ())): terminated
```